# Will element be visible to user agent with attribute hidden and css display: block?

Tags: html, css

I have a helper element with some CSS properties to aid my existing structure, that I don't want to be visible for anybody including user agent. I have html like this:

```
<button>
    <span>Real button text</span>
    <span style="display: block; visibility: hidden;" hidden>Fake helper text</span>
</button>
```

I know that CSS will override hidden attribute styles.
So the question is: will this element be visible to a user agent?

Comment: I have other styles on helper element besides display and visibility properties. Also in my case I cannot use pseudo elements!

Comment: yeah it will, you can hide it with server language like PHP or C#

Comment: do you need the text? if you hide it anyway?

Comment: Actually I've just found a solution. I've assigned a button element attribute data-button-title and in CSS to that button added pseudo element with the content: attr(data-button-title) and other necessary CSS properties. So in this case I can dispose of excess markup. Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be visible, if you want to hide it you can use php code for example.